# Maven: optional provided scope?

Tags: maven

I have a piece of code that is an adapter to other solutions (eg: A, B, C). User choose which solution (only one) they will use (via this adapter) in their project. Obviously, I still need to compile my code with A, B, C dependencies. But I don't want to have `compile` dependency neither on A, B, C - if user, for example, chooses solution A he does not need to include B or C.

Should I declare A,B,C dependency in my POM as:

1. `provided`
2. `provided`, but `optional`
3. just remove them from POM

In other words: does `provided` means that users MUST provide implementation in their runtime?

Thanx!

EDIT: similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860426/optional-dependency-in-maven)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `provided - optional`.

See linked question for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use provided. Presumably they're implementing an interface you have in common (either yours or a third party). You compile against the interface, and at runtime, somehow, they provide the implementation.

Comment: In other words, 'provided but optional' does not have sense? Does `provided` means that users MUST provide the implementation?

Comment: It depends on your code, but mostly the answer is yes. You are in great risk of a class not found exception if the dependency is not provided, although you may be able to code around that depending on how your app is configured. Generally, it's a bit hard. Optional dependencies aren't meant for this.