# Confused about the difference between <Optional> and <Scope> element when pulling dependency in Maven?

Tags: maven

My understanding of both is:

`<scope>` - "Use this dependency @ either `runtime,compile,test etc`"

`<optional>` - "Avoid pulling transitive dependencies and don't use this for compilation purposes"

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, please let me know when to use `<optional>` and why (its benefits).

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5861855/1199132 ?

Comment: The supposed duplicate has a much more limited scope than this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is nicely described in documentation (bolded part)

### [Optional Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

> Optional dependencies are used when it's not really possible (for whatever reason) to split a project up into sub-modules. **The idea is that some of the dependencies are only used for certain features in the project, and will not be needed if that feature isn't used**. Ideally, such a feature would be split into a sub-module that depended on the core functionality project...this new subproject would have only non-optional dependencies, since you'd need them all if you decided to use the subproject's functionality.

### [Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Depeandency_Scope)

> Dependency scope is used to limit the transitivity of a dependency, and also to affect the classpath used for various build tasks.

Also read: ["optional" dependency with scope "provided" in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860426/optional-dependency-in-maven/5861855#5861855)