# Sonarqube Analysis org.joda.convert ERROR

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

Why do I get this error:

> Class not found: org.joda.convert.ToString

None of my code uses this class (maven-based sonar analysis), and it doesn't seem to affect the analysis. However, I get worried whenever there are **"[ERROR]"** logs in the output. My exact command is:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar
```

I switched to this because someone in another related answer suggested this...

Comment: In addition, I believe that it is actually the sonarqube maven plug-in that is attempting to use the org.joda.convert.ToString (and FromString) classes. And, versions 1.2 and 1.8.1 of the joda-convert maven artifact are in my local repo...

Comment: Could you please provide the full logs ?

Comment: I will run an another analysis -- do you want debugging on?

Comment: see comment to benzonico -- thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is logged by the analyzer whenever it tries to complete a symbol during semantic analysis and cannot find a `.class` file.

This will happen wether your classes are using this class directly or transitively (via a dependence, or a dependence of a dependence, etc.). This is arguably an error per say in all cases but this is an important information for users to know because lacking some classes can lead to incomplete results (some issues might not be raised because symbols won't be resolved).

Comment: You can also read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/Yh2VgAM22B4) topic on SonarQube google group.

Comment: Well, okay, this answers the question, but it does not help at all. It is a **bug** in the Sonar Analyzer which is unable to include **optional** Maven dependencies. joda-time has an optional dependency to joda-convert, and as **many** people use this library, many have this problem (our company included).

Comment: Given what is an optional dependency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860426/optional-dependency-with-scope-provided-in-maven I would not qualify this behavior as a bug. However I agree that reporting missing class files is rather confusing right now and should most likely be improved.